# Appending dictionary to list of dictionaries puts double quotes around keywords

Tags: python, json, dictionary, yaml, robotframework

I want to accomplish:
Appending a Dictionary to an existing list of dictionaries and updating a value in that new dictionary.

What my problem is: 
When I read in my Dictionary from the .yaml RobotFramework puts double qoutes around the keywords and values as below.

in the .yaml I have

```
Vlan2: { u'IP': u'1.1.1.1', 
         u'DNS': {u'SN': u's2', u'PN': u's1'}, 
         u'SRoute': [{u'IF': u'eth0', u'Mask': u'0.0.0.0'}]
       }
```

but when I do

```
Collections.Set To Dictionary  ${Vlan2}  IP=2.2.2.2
```

and I log to console

```
Log To Console  ${Vlan2}
```

I get

```
[{ "u'IP'": "u'1.1.1.1'", 
   u'IP': '2.2.2.2', 
   "u'DNS'": {"u'SN'": "u's2'", "u'PN'": "u's1'"}, 
   "u'SRoute'": [{"u'IF'": "u'eth0'", "u'Mask'": "u'0.0.0.0'"}]
 }]
```

I think this is happening because Robot Framework is adding double qoutes when it reads in the values from the .yaml cause it to appear as a different keyword, but I cannot find out how to fix this.

It would be ideal to avoid the double qoutes all together since the JSON the info is going to is single qoute based as in the .yaml.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it really adding double quotes when reading?  Are you sure it's not just formatting output using double quotes when logging?  I don't think those double quotes are part of the values... just part of the logging output format.  You may be able to test this by logging just a single item of data, rather than a data structure.  You should really post your code if you want help to diagnose it.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and follow the advice.

Comment: the fact that you have yaml data with python-style unicode strings (`u'SN'`) seems suspicious. Are you certain that yaml supports this form of unicode string? How did you create this yaml file?

Comment: I agree with @BryanOakly that I am certain that the  dictionairy includes the u part of the key and value. That explains also the single quotes as they are part of the key/value  string now. So, remove the u and try again.

Comment: I know that this doesn't solve your problem but you can delete all double quotes fast converting the dict to string, replacing all instances of  the doubles quotes and back, using replace() and eval:


Calling d to your list, for example:

    `d = eval(str(d).replace('"', '')) `


Is a bit dirty solution but maybe is useful while you fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is quite a lot confusion going on here. This part of your YAML:

```
{ u'IP': u'1.1.1.1',
```

Starts a mapping (`{`) and gives a key-value pair. both key and value are scalars. The first scalar starts with a `u` and ends before the key indicator (`:`), so the content of the scalar is `u'IP'`. Note that this probably is not what you want, because you say:

> since the JSON the info is going to is single qoute based as in the .yaml.

You seem to think that you are using single-quoted scalars in your YAML when in fact, you are using *unquoted* scalars. In YAML, if a scalar does not start with a quotation mark (`'` or `"`), it is a plain scalar and further quotation marks inside it are parsed as content. Your scalars start with a `u` making them unquoted scalars. Your YAML should probably look like this:

```
Vlan2: { IP: 1.1.1.1, 
         DNS: {SN: s2, PN: s1}, 
         SRoute: [{IF: eth0, Mask: 0.0.0.0}]
       }
```

Another important thing to remember is that when loaded into Python, the representation style of a scalar is lost – it does not make a difference if it was single-quoted, double-quoted or unquoted in the YAML file.

Now let's look at the output: Here again, the strings are represented in textual form. This means that they are quoted by some means. The representation `"u'IP'"` matches exactly your input, the double quotes are *not* added to the string; they are just used as a means to tell you that the enclosed characters form a string.

Then there's this representation in the output: `u'IP'`. This is still a quoted string, just with the Python-specific representation of having a `u` in front indicating that this is a unicode string – its content is `IP`. **The `u`-prefixed representation does not exist in YAML and this is why your input does not work correctly**. In YAML, all input is unicode, usually encoded as UTF-8. The `u'IP'` in the output is the `IP` value you have set with your code. And because it did not match any existing dict key (as your original key, as explained, has the content `u'IP'`, represented in the output as `"u'IP'"`), it has been added as additional key to the dict.

Comment: I wonder how the OP managed to get a YAML file with Python unicode strings in them. If it wasn't for the `vlan2` key with trailing colon it looks like someone just `repr()`-ed a python dict.

Comment: Sometimes you just don't want to know ;)

Comment: So very true, but it makes it difficult to remove the actual cause of the problem. BTW if it was you how upvoted me on the YAML/docker-compose question, thanks for that, the other answerer there was a bit revengeful.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a file I get from an HTTP req and I have absolutely no control over it... and I have to PATCH it back with the same syntax otherwise it won't work.  I DID remove the u's and it updated correctly.. the problem is now that when I PATCH it they don't recognize my dicitonary entries since there are no u's... any advice or suggestions would be appreciated